# cannot get an pem file from authorized certificate ssl in heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, loopbackjs

I have a node.js application heberged in heroku, as you know heroku generate free certificate SSL automatically, but when I generate the pem file (I use openssl for this) from this certificate to include it in a terminal to let him communicate with server, the error 403 forbidden goes, and know I have 401 which is Unauthorized, can anyone help me how to access to the server from my terminal?

Here are the command that I use to generate `file.key`, `file.crt` and `file.pem`.

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048
openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key
openssl req -nodes -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
bash -c 'cat server.key server.crt server.pem
```